# Java REST Partial Update of boolean Fields

Tags: java, rest, jpa, boolean

I want to ask if there is any way to solve the following problem in an elegant way.

I have a Java Rest application using JPA and Jersey. I want to be able to partially update my models.

I do it by one method (update) which will check provided fields (!=null) and only update those ones It works great for all fields except boolean type fields.

I would really appreciate if you can give some ideas. I thought to Boolean type but it doesn't seem very elegant.

The resource part:

```
...

@PUT
@Path("{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update((@PathParam("id") long id, Event event) {
    Event _event = dao.find(id);

    if (event.getTitle()!=null) _event.setTitle(event.getTitle());

    // in case variable finished is not provided we should not change anything 
    // if (event.getFinished()!=null) _event.setFinished(event.getFinished());

    dao.update(id, _event);
}

...
```

The model part:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    private boolean finished = false;

    public Event(){}    

    // getters, setters

    ...
}
```

The javascript part:

```
// Those ones work
Event.post({id:12, title:"Meet with Joe", finished:true}  // update all fields
Event.post({id:12, title:"Meet with Barack", finished:false} // update all fields
Event.post({id:12, finished:false} // partial update of boolean fields

// How to achieve this one without affecting other boolean fields? 
Event.post({id:12, title:"Meet with Joe"}
// We haven't provided "finished" value. We don't want to change it. 
// But system will update unprovided boolean field value with default.
```

Comment: I think your model doesn't reflect your use case(s). Do you have multiple Event types but want to store it in one generic Event? Can you predict how many event variations will you have? Can you give some examples of that variations?

Comment: There are only one Event class. Additionally there are 10 other fileds such as id, startDate, endDate. when I want to use a field wchich should not be persisted, I just add @Transient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Instead of using Event in Post argument, it is better to use JsonObject:

```
...

@PUT
@Path("{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response update((@PathParam("id") long id, JSONObject json) {
    Event _event = dao.find(id);

    _event.setTitle(json.optString("title"));
    _event.setFinished(json.optBoolean("finished", _event.getFinished())); // if boolean value is not provided, we don't change it

    dao.update(id, _event);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically if you want to use your Event class to be able to express the concept of "a partial Event with some fields populated and some not", then having each field with a type that can be null does makes sense and IMO would be the "elegant" solution.

However, if this makes your Event now have the ability to have nulls on what is supposed to be a non-null field, just because you want to also use it in this update call - my guess is this is the part you don't like about it. (i.e. you are essentially using the same Event class to be a model object that directly represents a database record, and this partial representation of part of an Event that only has some fields filled out)

Another approach could be to get a simple Map in from the client (i.e. instead of "Event event" as your last param to update(), do "java.util.Map event") and just copy over the values it contains.  If you have to do this a lot you could use reflection to make the process easier to duplicate for multiple types of objects.

P.S. I don't have much experience with Jersey so I'm not sure if it will work correctly with java.util.Map (which is an interface) as the param type or if it needs a concrete class or possibly some other annotation(s).  But I'm sure that concept could be made to work if you like the approach.

Comment: It would be better to see a real example of how "java.util.Map event" should work. thanks